# Visualizar cores no Notepad++

Tags: cores, notepad++

Eu sempre usei o PHPStorm pra editar codigos, mas devido a ele ser muito pesado começou a travar muito ai resolvi usar o Notepad++, sempre gostei dele por ser muito leve, mas única coisa que atrapalha é que não consigo ver as cores hexadecimais, todos os codigos de cores que é inserido o programa não mostra qual cor é. No PHPStorm mostrava, como na foto abaixo. Algumas cores a gente memoriza mas em um site grande fica complicado. Sei que o Notepad++ tem plugins, alguém sabe de algum que faça mostrar as cores dos códigos ou algum plugin? Já procurei na internet mas não encontrei. Alguém sabe de alguma solução?

[image: Print do PHPStorm mostrando as cores]

Comment: Esse plugin sublinha a cor: https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp

Comment: Sugiro você usar o [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) em vez do notepade++ ele é melhor e também é leve

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam que eu saiba o Sublime tbm não mostra as cores dos códigos, se mostrar me fala como ativa pq eu nunca vi.

Comment: @vnbrs baixei o plugin exportei, reiniciei mas nada mudou, parece não ter efeito, como funciona isso, precisa de alguma outra configuração?

Comment: http://sublimetextdicas.com.br/mostrando-cores-em-arquivos-css/

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam nesse link tem a minha solução, consegui instalar e agora mostra as cores, muito obrigado, vou usar o Sublime agora, vlw